# Convert JSON object of array to Map of List<Map<String, dynamic>> with dynamic is a List<Object> in Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, rest, object

I'm trying to convert a JSON object array to an Object of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` which a `dynamic` part is a `List<Object>`.

**From** this:

```json
# RAW JSON
{
  "apidata_": [
    {"id":1,
    "string_":"a",
    "groupedString_":"G1"},
    {"id":2,
    "string_":"b",
    "groupedString_":"G2"},
    {"id":3,
    "string_":"c",
    "groupedString_":"G2"}
  ]
}
```

**To** this:

```json
# Result grouped JSON
{
  [
    {
      "groupedString_":"G1",
      "apidata_":[
        {"id":1,"string_":"a"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupedString_":"G2",
      "apidata_":[
        {"id":2,"string_":"b"},
        {"id":3,"string_":"c"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a Class for the object from object of RAW JSON API

```dart
class ListOfAPIData {
  ListOfAPIData({required this.apidata_});
  List<APIData> apidata_;

  factory ListOfAPIData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListOfAPIData(
      apidata_:
          List<APIData>.from(json['apidata_'].map((e) => APIData.fromJson(e))));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"data": List<dynamic>.from(apidata_.map((e) => e.toJson()))};
}

class APIData {
  APIData({
    required this.id_,
    required this.string_,
    required this.groupedString_,
  });
  int id_;
  String string_;
  String groupedString_;

  factory APIData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIData(
      id_: json["id_"],
      string_: json["string_"],
      groupedString_: json["groupedString_"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"id_": id_, "string_": string_, "groupedString_": groupedString_};
}
```

And this is a Class for the grouped object

```dart
class APIDataGrouped {
  APIDataGrouped({required this.groupedString_, required this.apidata_});
  String? groupedString_;
  List<APIData>? apidata_;

  factory APIDataGrouped.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => APIDataGrouped(
      groupedString_: json["groupedString_"],
      apidata_: List<APIData>.from(json['classname_']));

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['groupedString_'] = this.groupedString_;
    data['classname_'] = this.apidata_!.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}
```

I have manage to make a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` using `groupBy()`, but after that I've tried many ways and facing many errors like: `List<dynamic> is not a subtype of <Map<String, dynamic>>`, `FormatException: unexpected character`, etc. I alway get error because APIDataGrouped only accept `Map<String, dynamic>` as parameter but I cant provide it. Below is my Class for fetching data from the API.

```dart
class CallAPI {
  Future<ListOfAPIData> fetchdata() async {
    final respon = await get(Uri.http("serverAPI", '/path/of/API'));
    final body = jsonDecode(respon.body);
    final ListOfAPIData data;
    if (respon.statusCode == 200 && body != null) {
      data = ListOfAPIData.fromJson(body);
      return data;
    } else {
      throw "error";
    }
  }

  Future<APIDataGrouped> datagrouped() async {
    var data = await fetchdata();
    final g = groupBy(
      data.apidata_,
      (p0) => (p0 as APIData).groupedString_,
    );
    final d = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
    g.forEach((key, value) {
      d.add({
        "groupedString_": key,
        "apidata_": value
            .map((e) => Map.from(e.toJson())..remove('groupedString_'))
            .toList()
      });
    });
    final datafinal = d.reduce((value, element) {
      value.addAll(element);
      return value;
    });
    return APIDataGrouped.fromJson(datafinal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your api json called `jsonData` then you can use this approach:

```
var grouped = groupBy(jsonData["apidata_"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>,
    (Map value) => value['groupedString_']);
var result = grouped.entries.map((e) {
  return {
    "groupedString_": e.key,
    "apidata_": e.value
        .map((element) =>
            {"id": element["id"], "string_": element["string_"]})
        .toList()
  };
}).toList();

print("result = $result"); // result = [{groupedString_: G1, apidata_: [{id: 1, string_: a}]}, {groupedString_: G2, apidata_: [{id: 2, string_: b}, {id: 3, string_: c}]}]
```